# Find the matrix given the determinant

Tags: matrices, determinant

Is there a general method to find a 3x3, or 2x2 matrices, given the determinant? I want to do a project with my students when we start to study Systems of Equations. It would be interesting if the determinant is a prime number and then work backwards.

For example, I got this by playing around: if I let

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
       10 & -17\\
       31 & 2
     \end{bmatrix}$$

then the $\det(A)=547$, a prime number. Not sure if this would be a good mini project or not. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Determinants aren't unique; i.e., $\det A = \det B \not\Rightarrow A = B$.

Comment: I'm guessing you don't just want to find a matrix but rather a "nice" matrix. Say one with all integer coefficients? Otherwise given the determinant of a matrix is linear in each of its elements you can just set all elements except one to 1 and solve a linear equation to get the remaining entry so that you get your desired determinant.

Comment: I think your question needs a few more details. I guess you want integer coefficients in you matrix, or not?
In that case your question is about diophantine equations and when $ad-bc = n$ admits solutions (and how many solutions exists) when $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Z}$. 
In other cases there could be an infinite numer of matrices associated to a single determinant, and I don't get the point with prime numbers.

Comment: Yes, I wanted integer coefficients. The purpose of the prime number is to tie in to a previous project completed in class.

Answer (score 7):

Start with the diagonalized form $A=PDP^{-1}$ where $D=\mathrm{diag}([\lambda_1, \lambda_2,\cdots,\lambda_n])$.  You can then choose the diagonal terms of $D$ such that $\det(A)=\lambda_1 \lambda_2\cdots\lambda_n$.  Finally you can create a similar matrix by choosing any invertable $P$.

Answer (score 1):

Recall if you let $A$ be a $n \times n$ matrix in lower (or upper) triangular form, then $$\det(A) = \prod_{i = 1}^n a_{ii}.$$ Using this, you can select your entries along the diagonal such that their product equals whatever value you desire and then you may fill in the remaining entries of the matrix however you desire.